# In Javascript, is it true that function aliasing works as long as the function being aliased doesn't touch "this"?

Tags: javascript, binding, call, apply

In Javascript, if we are aliasing a function (or, assign a "reference to a function" to another variable), such as in:

```
f = g;
f = obj.display;
obj.f = foo;
```

all the 3 lines above, they will work as long as the function / method on the right hand side doesn't touch `this`?  Since we are passing in all the arguments, the only way it can mess up is when the function / method on the right uses `this`?

Actually, line 1 is probably ok if `g` is also a property of `window`?  If `g` is referencing `obj.display`, then the same problem is there.

In line 2, when `obj.display` touches `this`, it is to mean the `obj`, but when `f` is invoked,  the `this` is `window`, so they are different.

In line 3, it is the same: when `f` is invoked inside of `obj`'s code, then the `this` is `obj`, while `foo` might be using `this` to refer to `window` if it was a property of `window`. (global function).

So line 2 can be written as

```
f = function() { obj.display.apply(obj, arguments) }
```

and line 3:

```
obj.f = function() { foo.apply(window, arguments) }
```

Is this the correct method? And are there other methods besides this?

Comment: This made me think of M.C. Hammer

Comment: i know.  i was trying not to mention that in the original question.

Comment: Congratulations, you've just discovered the reason why I hate object oriented programming in Javascript. 
Due to the the lack of bound functions, you always have to mind the context and (thus) what this points to.  Now you can move on to a real OOP language (sorry :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically yes, however, in JavaScript functions are first class objects, so there it is not really aliasing. What you are doing is assigning the value of a variable to another variable, an in this case the value just happens to be a function.

The magic *this* variable however is a little bit different. In JavaScript methods are not bound to a class or an object, like they are in most other languages. When you call a method the *this* is set by the dot operator, or by the *apply* or *call* methods. It works like this:

```
var i = 1;
var f = function () { alert(this.i); }
f(); // in a browser, alerts 1, because this will be window if it isn't anything else.

var obj = { i: 10 };
obj.g = f;
obj.g(); // alerts 10, because the dot binds this to obj

var other_obj = { i: 23 };
f.apply(g); // alerts 23, because now apply binds this to other_obj
```

You can bind methods to objects by using closures:

```
var f = function () { alert(this.i); }
var obj = { i: 10 };

obj.m = function () { f.apply(obj); }
obj.m(); // alerts 10

var g = obj.m;
g(); // alerts 10, because now the closure is called, which binds this correctly.
```

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of "this" and scopes as they apply to functions, especially callbacks, seems to be a classic JavaScript "gotcha".

Dojo has a hitch() method which addresses the problem, giving a nice way to get the expected context for callback methods. I guess a non-dojo developer could have a look at the Dojo hitch() code to borrow the ideas.

This [article](http://dojocampus.org/content/2008/07/15/dojohitch-and-scope-again/) explains some aspects of the "this" problem and how to use Dojo hitch().

Answer (score 1):

'this' will only refer to the right object inside your function if you invoke an object in this way:

```
obj.f();
```

This will never work, as javascript lacks support for "bound functions" (doesn't remember what object a method belongs to):

```
var x = context.lineTo;
x(10,10);
```

lineTo will get confused as 'this' now points to the window or current function object instead of its expected context. So indeed, you always need apply in your case.